# How to use JavaScript to rendering copied format string?

Tags: javascript, web

#### I want to render string formats when I paste.

For example:

1. **Copy from vscode.**
   [image]
2. **And paste to Google Docs.**
   [image]

It's display text and color format accurately. How does it do it?

Sorry I'm not a native speaker of English.

Comment: Please don't post code in screenshot images. Post the raw code from your application. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Are you asking WHY code segments colors are the same on vscode and google google docs or HOW this is done?

Comment: @Krish the code just a example, just ignore it.

Comment: and @A.Meshu yes.

Comment: Don't know if this answers your question but with php you can use `highlight_string`. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php

Comment: With `js` you can dig to this plugins and see how it been done: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/140/top-5-best-code-syntax-highlighter-javascript-plugins

Comment: @A.Meshu thank you. But it's seems not my need. I guess when I execute copy, os may copy text and invisibility format code, I need that.